# Prove that if $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }a_{n}=1$ then $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }a_{1}+a_{2}+\ldots +a_{n}=\infty $

Tags: sequences-and-series, monotone-functions

Would appreciate some help with proving the following statement:

Let $a_{n}$ be a sequence, and $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }a_{n}=1 $.

Prove that $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }a_{1}+a_{2}+\ldots +a_{n}=\infty $.
It's easy to see that if $a_{n}$ is monotonically decreasing, then we can choose the sequence $b_{n}=\sum ^{n}a_{n}k=1$, then $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }b_{n}=\infty$ and since $\forall n\in \mathbb{N} \left( a_{n+1}\leq a_{n}\right)$, we can assume that $\lim _{n\rightarrow \infty }a_{1}+a_{2}+\ldots +a_{n}=\infty $, but what happens when $a_{n}$ is monotonically increasing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $a_n \to 1$ then there is $N \in \mathbb N$ such that $a_n \ge 1/2$ for all $n \ge N$. Therefore, for $n \ge N$,
$$b_n = \sum_{k = 1}^n a_k \ge (n - N) \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{k = 1}^N a_k$$
and $(n - N)1/2$ goes to $\infty$ for $n \to \infty.$

Answer (score 5):

There exists $m$ such that $a_n >\frac 1  2$ for $n \geq m$. So, for $n >m$ we have  $$a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_{m-1}+a_m+a_{m+1}+\cdots+a_n$$ $$ > a_1+a_2+...+a_{m-1}+\frac {n-m+1} 2 \to \infty$$ as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

There is some $n\in\Bbb N$ suche that $n\geqslant N\implies a_n\geqslant\frac12$. So, if $n\geqslant N$,$$a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_n\geqslant a_1+\cdots+a_{N-1}+\frac{n-N-1}2.$$Can you take it from here?